# JpegBitmapEncoder leaves gray streak at end of file?

Tags: wpf, encoding, bitmap, jpeg

I'm working with the WPF imaging components in an attempt to do some simple image manipulation.  I'm roughly following the MS article on [How to Encode & Decode a JPEG Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970689.aspx).

My code is simple:

```
BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();

bi.BeginInit();
bi.UriSource = new Uri("D:\\Temp\\StackOverflowCapture.png");
//bi.DecodePixelWidth = 1024;
//bi.DecodePixelHeight = 768;
bi.EndInit();

var jpg                  = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
    jpg.QualityLevel     = 90;
    //jpg.FlipHorizontal = false;
    //jpg.FlipVertical   = false;
    jpg.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bi));

var fs = new FileStream("D:\\Temp\\StackOverflow_Result.jpg", FileMode.Create);

jpg.Save( fs );
jpg = null;
```

The code snippet creates an odd artifact, where the last few "lines" are a block of solid gray.  It's almost as if the encoder just ran out of pixels to write.    The amount of gray varies by a factor of 2x or 3x depending on the image I use as input (various resolutions, jpeg, png) or the options I enable (forcing resolution on decode).  The net effect is the same, however, as you can see from the images below.

My source image is :

> [image]

Output image ( note the gray band at the bottom):

> [image]

What's going on here?  How do I get a clean convert?

Comment: Just a wild guess, but does this also happen when you set `bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;`?

Comment: There is no change in behavior when I set `bi.CacheOption`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was definitely a short circuit between the ears.  For the sake of others with similar frailties, however, I'm answering my own question.

**You need to close/flush the stream.**  Alternately, it would be good practice to create `fs` in a `using` block.

Modified code is thus:

```
BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();

bi.BeginInit();
bi.UriSource = new Uri("D:\\Temp\\StackOverflow_Source.png");
bi.EndInit();

var jpg                  = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
    jpg.QualityLevel     = 90;
    jpg.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bi));

var fs = new FileStream("D:\\Temp\\StackOverflow_Result.jpg", FileMode.Create);

jpg.Save( fs );
fs.close();       <--- duh, flush the stream to disk
jpg = null;
```