# How to save image using JpegBitmapEncoder

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.5, jpegbitmapencoder

According to the image encoding example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748873.aspx#_imageformats) I should be able to use [JpegBitmapEncoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Media.Imaging.JpegBitmapEncoder.aspx) to encode an image for saving as a jpeg file but get this compile error:

> *error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Controls.Image' to 'System.Uri'*

I don't see a way (property or method in Image) to get `System.Uri` from Image.
What am I missing?

The Image xaml code is

```
<Image Name="ColorImage"/>
```

The SaveImage C# is

```
...
SaveImage(ColorImage, path);
...
private void SaveImage(Image image, string path)
{
    var jpegEncoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
    jpegEncoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(image));
    using (var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        jpegEncoder.Save(fs);
    }
}
```

The code below (taken mostly from the [kinect-sdk](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh855347.aspx)) streams 640 x 480 RBG to a [WriteableBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx) at 30 Fps (the kinect [ColorImageFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.colorimageformat.aspx) is RgbResolution640x480Fps30).

```
using (var colorImageFrame = allFramesReadyEventArgs.OpenColorImageFrame())
{
    if (colorImageFrame == null) return;
    var haveNewFormat = currentColorImageFormat != colorImageFrame.Format;
    if (haveNewFormat)
    {
        currentColorImageFormat = colorImageFrame.Format;
        colorImageData = new byte[colorImageFrame.PixelDataLength];
        colorImageWritableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(
            colorImageFrame.Width, 
            colorImageFrame.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null);
        ColorImage.Source = colorImageWritableBitmap;
    }
    // Make a copy of the color frame for displaying.
    colorImageFrame.CopyPixelDataTo(colorImageData);
    colorImageWritableBitmap.WritePixels(
        new Int32Rect(0, 0, colorImageFrame.Width, colorImageFrame.Height),
        colorImageData,
        colorImageFrame.Width*Bgr32BytesPerPixel,
        0);
}
```

Comment: See this [JpegBitmapEncoder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13844074/jpegbitmapencoder-leaves-gray-streak-at-end-of-file)

Comment: @Dumitru Chirutac: Already did. JpegBitmapEncoder is linked in the original post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private void SaveImage(string path)
{
    var jpegEncoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
    jpegEncoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(colorImageWritableBitmap));
    using (var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        jpegEncoder.Save(fs);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem occurs, because you pass an `Image` to `BitmapFrame.Create`. `Image`is more common in Windows Forms. A simple approach would be to create a `MemoryStream` first and the pass this:

```
private void SaveImage(Image image, string path)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        image.Save(ms,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        var jpegEncoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
        jpegEncoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(ms));
        using (var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            jpegEncoder.Save(fs);
        }
    }
```

Addition (see conversation in comments):

you could try to use the `CopyPixels` method on the writeableBitmap object and copy the pixels to a byte array which you load to a `MemoryStream` and the write it to a Jpeg File withe the `JpegBitmapEncoder`. But it's just a guess.

This could work, too:

```
     private void SaveImage (WriteableBitmap img, string path)
     {
         FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
         JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
         encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(img));
         encoder.Save(stream);
         stream.Close();
     }
```

You will just have to extract the WriteableBitmap from your Image control

Comment: There does not seem to be a `Save` definition or method for `Image`. The compiler complaint is: `error CS1061: 'System.Windows.Controls.Image' does not contain a definition for 'Save' and no extension method 'Save' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.Image' could be found`

Comment: I got that wrong. I thaught you were talking about 'System.Drawing.Image`

Comment: How do you set the Image and where do you get it from?

Comment: Since it was a long answer I modified the original post to show how the image is set

Comment: +1 for hint that I need to look at how the image is set. Added working code as answer. Can't set it as accepted for a couple of days.

Answer (score 0):

Try: `BitmapFrame.Create(image.Source)`

Comment: I think this will only help with images read from storage and not for images that were created dynamically. He could also joust pass the path to the image ;-)

Comment: @jlew: Tried `BitmapFrame.Create(image.Source)` first. It produces the same compiler error.